# How do I conditionally highlight cells based off data from another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, formulas

I have two tabs in a Google Sheets file. One contains data to display (auto-generated), and another contains information about availability. They appear as such, where the sheets correspond 1-to-1:

```
User tally
       A        B      C      D
  +----------+------+------+------+
1 |          | OS 1 | OS 2 | OS 3 |
  +----------+------+------+------+
2 | Device A | 12   | 0    | 512  |
  +----------+------+------+------+
3 | Device B | 0    | 156  | 18   |
  +----------+------+------+------+
4 | Device C | 0    | 0    | 0    |
  +----------+------+------+------+


OS availability
       A        B      C      D
  +----------+------+------+------+
1 |          | OS 1 | OS 2 | OS 3 |
  +----------+------+------+------+
2 | Device A | 1    | 0    | 1    |
  +----------+------+------+------+
3 | Device B | 0    | 1    | 1    |
  +----------+------+------+------+
4 | Device C | 0    | 0    | 1    |
  +----------+------+------+------+
```

As you can see, the Devices for which an OS is not supported all have `0` users, as expected. However, there are some Devices that do support an OS, but `0` users have that combination (i.e. Device B on OS 3, and Device C entirely).

In my `User tally` spreadsheet, I want to use **Conditional Formatting** to change the background and text color of unsupported combinations to the same thing, making it appear as if the cell is completely blank. However, I want supported combinations to display their `0`, indicating that users *can* use this combination, but don't for some reason.

I tried placing the following into the Conditional Formatting panel for `'User tally'!B2:D4` as a `Custom formula is` (hoping `B2` would change per-cell like it does when you paste a formula across many cells), but it didn't appear to have an effect:

```
EQUAL('OS support'!B2, '0')
```

**How do I use Conditional Formatting to change the color of each cell based on counterpart data from another table?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following into the Conditional Formatting panel for `'User tally'!B2:D4` as a Custom formula:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("'OS support'!A1"),row(B2)-1,COLUMN(B2)-1)=0
```

Comment: Beautiful! Works wondrously. Thank you.